# Express sending files itself without a response body

Tags: node.js, express

I didn't specify the res body yet express is serving index.html file by default.

My file structure looks like this

- node_modules
- public

  - img
  - abc.html
  - index.html
  - script.js
  - style.css
- package.json
- server.js

Does it have something to do with express.static? What should I do to only send a specific file?
I'm a complete beginner.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  
})

app.listen(7000);
console.log('App is running on port 7000');
```

Comment: It's because of this: `app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));`. Like any normal web server, `express.static` will serve `index.html` file when you request for a blank route like `/`. So it is intercepting the request **before** your code

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does have to do with static!

If you check [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) it explains that you are loading the child public directory, and it is looking inside there for a static html file to render, which is index.html by default as seen [Here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static).

Comment: Maybe you can mention that the solution is to move the express.static below his own route handler